# turning numeric matrix into an array

Tags: r, f#

I have the following prediction in F# as a numeric matrix:

```ml
let predictresults = R.predict_lm(mymdl, mytest |> R.as_data_frame).AsNumericMatrix
```

However, I need the predicted results (of several years) as an array. Could anybody give me a tip on how to do this? I tried `Matrix.toSeq |> Seq.toArray` however, I receive the error message that `NumericMatrix` is not compatible with `Matrix`.

Comment: You don't say how you're using R from F# – is [this](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/R.NET/RDotNet/Matrix(T)/M/CopyTo) what you're looking for?

Comment: I use the following: open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.graphics
open RProvider.stats 
open RDotNet
open RProvider.``base``

Comment: All I want to do is to get the predicted values (using R in F#) as an array so that I can compute my prediction errors. I have them as a numeric matrix and cannot convert to array.

Comment: Have you tried [`predictresults.ToArray ()`](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet/blob/master/R.NET/Matrix.cs#L297)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `ToArray` method rather than anything in the `Matrix` module:

```ml
let predictresultsarr = predictresults.ToArray ()
```

While I have no first-hand experience with it, R.NET appears to be a C#-oriented library, and as such the `Matrix` module is not as fleshed out as it could be (`Matrix.toArray` or `NumericMatrix.toArray` would certainly be idiomatic). As such, you may want to consider using a more F#-oriented library such as the [F# R Type Provider](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/), which is an F# layer on top of R.NET.